# Getting a range of numbers with recursion using python

Tags: python, recursion

I'm struggling with this question. Basically, I need to create a recursive function that takes a start, end, and range as parameters:

```
ex. recurs(6,10,range(4,17)) should return: [6,7,8,9,10]
```

I've figured my base case out but I'm struggling with the rest of the logic. I've coded something but it isn't outputting anything. Here is my code and any advice would be appreciated:

```
def recurs(start, end, nums):
    if not nums:
        return []
    elif(nums[0] >= start) and (nums[0] <= end):
        return nums[0] + recurs(start, end, nums[1:])
```

Calling `recurs(4,9,range(1,10))` is not returning anything.

Comment: None of your if statements are satisfied with that example, so nothing is explicitly returned.  `nums[0]` is less than your `start` input.  Depending on how exactly you want that case handled, you're going to have to account for it using a separate if clause or changing your current one.

Comment: There are at least two problems. 1. `range(...)` does not return a list, so you should call `recurs(4,9,list(range(1,10)))`.
2. At the first step when `nums[0] = 1` neither of conditions is true and function silently ends returning nothing. No recursion steps are executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
def recurs(start, end, nums):
    status  = True
    while status:
        # print("nums is :", nums)
        if not len(nums):
            return []
        elif(nums[0] >= start) and (nums[0] <= end):
            ret_val = [nums[0]] + recurs(start, end, nums[1:])
            # print("Retval is :", ret_val)
            return ret_val
        else:
            nums = nums[1:]


ret = recurs(6,10, list(range(4,17)))
print(ret)
```

Output :

```
[6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

You can uncomment the print lines and see the flow. You would understand the problem with code you tried.